# RichTextBox -- Preserving Horizontal Spacing

Tags: winforms, richtextbox

I would like to copy some lines from a .txt file into a RichTextBox in a Windows Form.

When I view the lines in Notepad++, they align evenly:

```
        |  a. XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX . . .XXXXX__________  XXXXXXX__________ |      
        |  b. XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX . . . . . . . . . . . . . . __________ |
```

When I add them to a RichTextBox, the alignment is lost, and the vertical bar at the end of the second line is indented twenty or so characters.

Does anyone have any suggestions about how I can preserve the alignment that I see in Notepad++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a fixed-width spaced font, like `Courier New` or `Consolas`.

Comment: Wow -- a simple answer, but one that never occurred to me.  Thank you very much.